Where are the sleep/lock inhibitors kepts in D-BUS
I'm trying to find what is causing this Power Management display in my KDE Plasma (Kubuntu 24.04, Plasma 5.27.11):

Because if I ask on D-Bus I don't see these:
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1 --method org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.ListInhibitors
([
('sleep', 'signal-desktop', 'Application cleanup before suspend', 'delay', uint32 1000, uint32 474396), 
('sleep', 'ModemManager', 'ModemManager needs to reset devices', 'delay', 0, 1829), 
('sleep', 'Screen Locker', 'Ensuring that the screen gets locked before going to sleep', 'delay', 1000, 2601), 
('handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch', 'PowerDevil', 'KDE handles power events', 'block', 1000, 2713), 
('sleep', 'UPower', 'Pause device polling', 'delay', 0, 2287), 
('sleep', 'NetworkManager', 'NetworkManager needs to turn off networks', 'delay', 0, 1757), 
('shutdown', 'Unattended Upgrades Shutdown', 'Stop ongoing upgrades or perform upgrades before shutdown', 'delay', 0, 1984)],)

Is there another place to search (I look with qdbusviewer but couldn't find an object with a usable call to list everything)?
Furthermore, despite the display, I'm still able to lock & sleep...

Are you looking in the correct bus? KDE-specific inhibitors would be handled by one of the session bus services (most likely PowerDevil?).

Looked in both buses. Yes, there are other possibly power-related entries, but they don't show a call to report inhibitors like the ListInhibitors above.

Are there any properties then? Have you tried using dbus-monitor to find out what KTorrent calls when paused/unpaused, for example?
